# Where can I find replacement screws?

Tags: maintenance, parts

I have a handful of rusty screws on my bike; where can I find such small parts?
[image: rusty handlebar bolts][image: rusty stem bolts]

Comment: These look like M4/5/6 socket head machine screws. Most hardware stores should stock them. Make sure you buy stainless to avoid rust in the future!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most bike screws are 4, 5, or 6 mm allen bolts. Any bike shop will also have these in stock. You could probably hunt up some stuff in your local hardware store, just bring your bike along.

On the net:

- [Loose Screws bicycle small parts](http://www.loosescrews.com/)
- [Planet Bike](http://ecom1.planetbike.com/smallparts.html) does free shipping on small parts (scroll down a bit to rack hardware and such)

Answer (score 5):

Bike shops usually carry even the most obscure screws. It's a good thing to get to know your local bike shop and be "friendly" with its staff, when you're missing small parts like that (a screw or two, or small replaceable parts from the derailleur let's say) they might even give it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Those are called stem bolts. I'm not sure what size those are, but all bmx stems use the same sized bolts and you can get a new set of 6 for under $10 at your local(online) bike shop.

Answer (score 1):

Many decent hardware stores (at least in the US) will also carry them. Look in the fastener section of the store, where I usually find them is in the collection of small boxes that holds all of the oddball hardware.